# Conormal Derivative and Green Function in integral

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, greens-function

I have the following question that starts from this expression:
$$
u(x)=\int_{\partial B}\left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(y) \Gamma(y-x)+u(y) \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial n}(y-x)\right) d \sigma(y) .
$$

If $h \in C^2(\bar{B})$ is harmonic and Green function $G(x, y)=\Gamma(y-x)-h(y)$, the above integral leads us to
$$
u(x)=\int_{\partial B}\left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(y) G(x, y)+u(y) \frac{\partial G}{\partial n_y}(x, y)\right) d \sigma(y) .
$$

I have tried to develop it but I have not been able to reach the second integral. The derivative that appears is the normal derivative used in PDEs and its expression is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=(\nabla u)^{T}\cdot n$ where $n$ is a vector. Developing the integrand, I have reached this point:
\begin{equation*}
    -\frac{\partial u(y)}{\partial n}\cdot ( G(x,y) + h(y) ) + u(y)\cdot\frac{\partial (G(x,y) + h(y))}{\partial n}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    -\frac{\partial u(y)}{\partial y}\cdot ( G(x,y) + h(y) ) + u(y)\cdot \nabla (G(x,y)+h(y))^{T}\cdot n
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    -\frac{\partial u(y)}{\partial y}\cdot ( G(x,y) + h(y) ) + u(y)\cdot \left(\frac{\partial ( G + h)}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial (G +h)}{\partial y}\right) \cdot (n_x , n_y)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    -\frac{\partial u(y)}{\partial y}\cdot ( G(x,y) + h(y) ) + u(y)\cdot \left(\frac{\partial ( G )}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial (G +h)}{\partial y}\right) \cdot (n_x , n_y)
\end{equation*}
If we continue operating and simplifying, it can be seen that we do not reach the desired expression. Is the procedure wrong or is there a calculation error?

This whole problem comes from the book "Stable solutions of elliptic partial differential equations" by Louis Dupaigne, page 235.

---

given any function $g \in C(\partial B)$, there exists a unique function $u \in C^2(B) \cap C(\bar{B})$ solving
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
-\Delta u=0 & \text { in } B, &  \\
u=g & \text { on } \partial B . & \end{array}\right.
$$
Suppose for the moment that $u \in C^2(\bar{B})$ is a solution of this problem.
Fix a point $x \in B$, multiply by $\Gamma(y-x)$, where $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of the Laplace operator and integrate over $B \backslash B(x, \varepsilon)$, $\varepsilon>0$. Then,
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
0=\int_{B \backslash B(x, \varepsilon)}-\Delta u(y) \Gamma(y-x) d y= & \\
\int_{\partial B}\left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(y) \Gamma(y-x)+u(y) \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial n}(y-x)\right) d \sigma(y)- & \begin{array}{l}
\end{array} \\
\int_{\partial B(x, \varepsilon)}\left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(y) \Gamma(y-x)+u(y) \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial n}(y-x)\right) d \sigma(y) .
\end{array}
$$

Letting $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, it is not hard to deduce that cuando integras va a tender a
$$
u(x)=\int_{\partial B}\left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(y) \Gamma(y-x)+u(y) \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial n}(y-x)\right) d \sigma(y) .
$$
And this continue above in my intial answer.

And the expression of $\Gamma$ when $N\neq 2$ is
\begin{equation}
  \Gamma(x)=\Gamma(r)=\frac{1}{N(N-2)|B|}r^{2-N}
 \end{equation}
where $|B|$ denotes the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$, and by
\begin{equation}
  \Gamma(x)=\Gamma(r)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}ln(r)
 \end{equation}
if N=2- And where r=|x|, r^2=x^2_1 + \ldots + x^2_N

Comment: $\partial u/\partial n=n\cdot \nabla u$, not $\Delta u$.

Comment: Yes thank, a mistake while i was writing the question.  Regarding how to get from the first integral to the second, is there no other way?

Comment: What is $B$? It is an arbitrary domain, or is it a ball?

Comment: Thank for answer. It is a ball with arbitrary dimension

Comment: And, I suppose $h$ is the boundary data of $u$? What exactly is $\Gamma$ ?

Comment: I think that h isn't a boundary data, problem given a boundary data g and it is used in the last part of the resolution.
$\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of the Operator and it have two expressions if $N\neq 2$ o $N=2$.

I have just edited my questions with more information from that book

Comment: I [think](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464667/greens-function-on-unit-ball) $h(x,y)=\Gamma\big(|x|~(y-|x|^{-2}x)\big)$, is that right?

Comment: The given expression of the Green function you have shared in the link is equal to Dupaigne’s book expression but with different nomenclature.  Specifically, it seems two pages later page237. But for the question that I have asked at the beginning I think it is not necessary to know an explicit expression of h, only that it is harmonious.

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial G}{\partial n_y}$ ?

Comment: Oh I see, $\partial G/\partial n_y$ is $n\cdot \nabla_y G$

Comment: The two integrals will be equal if $\int_{\partial B} n(y)\cdot \bigg( h(x,y)\nabla u(y) -u(y)\nabla_y h(x,y)\bigg) \mathrm d^{m-1}y=0$ , so I think showing this is key

Comment: Note also that $n(y)=y$ in this case because our surface is a sphere